# strpos проверить свойство объекта на наличие в нем текста

Tags: php, объекты, properties

Я пытаюсь проверить определенное свойство объекта на наличие в нем текста nobr В этом свойстве лежит html-код -теги и какой-либо текст.

Можно ли написать так?

```
foreach($obj->getElementsByTagName('tr') as $tr)

    $tds = $tr->getElementsByTagName('td');
    if($tds->item(0)->strpos(item(0), 'nobr', !== false)){
        continue;
    }
```

Я получаю ошибку валидации, к сожалению:

PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '!==' (T_IS_NOT_IDENTICAL) in your code on line 4

Что нужно исправить, подскажите, пожалуйста?
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что за диковинная конструкция такая в аргументе функции: `!== false` Вытащите из аргумента функции, то что Вы написали за скобку так: `if($tds->item(0)->strpos(item(0), 'nobr') !== false)`

Comment: Спасибо большое!